# How to run a python script in flutter without relying on api?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

So I have a python script that take the image, process and return the processed image. Now what I want is that I want that functionality in my flutter application so I want to know whether is there any way to run that script inside the flutter other than API's?

Comment: There's package:python_ffi, but why not just write the code in dart?  It can't be that complicated, and most of the work is probably being done in libraries that you'd also have to figure out how to include.